# HTML Page scrollable without any content

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, footer, scrollable

i made a simple html-page using bootstrap (only navbar and footer). Now the site is scrollable ... why?

https://www.checkmobility.de

Heres my Footer CSS:

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px; /* Margin bottom by footer height */
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  line-height: 50px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

.container {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of using line-height in the footer, it's causing an overflow. Use `overflow:auto` to fix it...

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  line-height: 50px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/PvhX4Z7ZYx